# Android Studio, masOS Sierra Scrolling trackpad scrolling not smooth

Tags: android-studio-2.2, macos-sierra

I have recently updated to masOS Sierra and have been using Android Studio 2.2 the trackpad scrolling is not very smooth (i.e. it scrolls very fast) is anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This fixes scrolling issue on mac os Mojave with Android Studio 3.2

Comment: My scrolling had a bit delay and lack of smoothness. When I switched to no antialiasing, it turned more smooth. Grayscale is a better option for me because no antialiasing may strain your eye.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "System Preferences..." -- "Accessibility" -- "Mouse & Trackpad" -- "Trackpad Options...".
Uncheck "Scrolling" and check again.
Done